# Angular 2: How to use Http in ES5?

Tags: angular

Currently, I'm playing around with Angular 2. I try to use Http in ES5 but can't make it working. The error says, "Http is not defined".

Here is my code:

```
function Service() {}
Service.prototype.greeting = function() {
  return 'Hello';
};

var Cmp = ng.
  Component({
    selector: 'cmp',
    providers: [Service],
    directives: [ng.NgFor],
    injectors: [ng.Http, ng.HTTP_PROVIDERS],
    templateUrl: 'hello.html'
  }).
  Class({
    constructor: [Service, function Cmp(service) {
      this.greeting = service.greeting();
      ng.Http.get('people.json');
    }],
  });

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  ng.bootstrap(Cmp);
});
```

Can anybody help me on solving this? Thank you.

Comment: Need more information. What is the error you are getting?

Comment: I'm sorry for lack information. I got '..Http is not defined' error.

Comment: Is "ng" defined? Can you see if Http objec is a part of ng?

Comment: I don't see any Http object inside of ng, so how do I define the Http? Is it on another module? I only use https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.44/angular2.sfx.dev.js module (default Angular 2 ES5 in Plunker).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I finally managed to solve my own problem.

Here is my code:

```
function Service() {}
Service.prototype.greeting = function() {
  return 'Hello';
};

var Cmp = ng.
  Component({
    selector: 'cmp',
    providers: [Service, ngHttp.HTTP_PROVIDERS],
    template: '{{greeting}}, {{result.name}}!'
  }).
  Class({
    constructor: [Service, ngHttp.Http, function Cmp(service, Http) {
      this.greeting = service.greeting();
      this.result = {};
      this.http = Http;
      this.mapPeople().subscribe(function(result){
        this.result = result;
      }.bind(this));
    }],
    mapPeople: function(){
      return this.http.get('people.json').map(function (res) {
              return res.json();
          });
    }
  });

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  ng.bootstrap(Cmp);
});
```

Turn out, the Http object is in ngHttp. I think since Angular 2 is currently still in Alpha version and rapidly changing, the documentation is lacking. I hope this would help people out there who have the same problem as I had.

Comment: this is the best example of using ngHttp in ES5 I've found. Thanks!

Comment: what file do you include to achieve this? I get either ngHttp not defined or System is not defined or require is not defined based on which file i include. I just cannot get this to work.

Comment: Same here, ngHttp not defined... What should go in app.module.js?

Answer (score 6):

For Angular 2 Beta version, It works in following way

```
(function(app) {

app.MyName = ng.core
  .Component({
    selector: 'my-name',
    template: '<span>Dave</span>',
    providers: [ng.http.HTTP_PROVIDERS]
  })
  .Class({
    constructor: [ng.http.Http, function(http) {

    }]
  });

app.HelloApp =
  ng.core.Component({
    selector: 'hello-app',
    template: '<h1>Hello Angular 2!</h1><my-name></my-name>',
    directives: [app.MyName]
  })
  .Class({
    constructor: function(){}
  });
})(window.app || (window.app = {}));
```

Comment: This results in the error: only instances of Provider and Type are allowed

Answer (score 0):

To get this to work with the beta version I had to change ngHttp to ng.http