# Using Angular2 HTTP Service in ES5 code

Tags: angular, angular2-services

How to use the HTTP service provided by Angular2 in ES5 code? [Here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/ts-to-js.html#!#query-decorators) is the TypeScript example.

I basically need examples of GET and POST requests.

The example shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33458481/angular-2-how-to-use-http-in-es5) is not working. `get` seems to be undefined.

Here is an example that doesn't work:

```
    var SearchResultComponent = ng.core.Component({
        selector: "search-result",
        viewProviders: [ng.http.HTTP_PROVIDERS],
        templateUrl: "componentTemplates/SearchResult.html"
    }).Class({
        constructor: [ng.http.HTTP_PROVIDERS, function(http) {
            this.params = params;
            this.http = http;
        }],
        ngOnInit: function(){

            console.log(this.http.get); //undefined
        }
    })
```

Comment: You could make it a valid question by adding the code that demonstrates what you tried and the exact error message you got. A Plunker that demonstrates the issue wouldn't hurt either.

Comment: done. edited post and added an example.

Answer (score 0):

In the constructor of your `SearchResultComponent` component, you need use `ng.http.Http` and not HTTP providers:

```
var SearchResultComponent = ng.core.Component({
    selector: "search-result",
    viewProviders: [ng.http.HTTP_PROVIDERS],
    templateUrl: "componentTemplates/SearchResult.html"
}).Class({
    constructor: [ng.http.Http, function(http) { // <-----
        this.params = params;
        this.http = http;
    }],
    ngOnInit: function(){

        console.log(this.http.get); //undefined
    }
});
```

In your case, it wasn't the `Http` object that was injected...

Providers can be specified when boostrapping your application, in the `providers` attribute or the `viewProviders` attribute (like you did).

See this plunkr for a use of HTTP with Angular2 and ES5: https://plnkr.co/edit/oM4gTgW5Q7gpR8Qderjj.

Comment: what is the difference between viewProviders and the array values assigned to the constructor. I mean difference between HTTP_PROVIDERS and ng.http.Http?

Comment: viewProviders / providers allow you to define providers (entities responsible of creating instances of something) and constuctor parameters to what you want to inject (i.e. objects created by providers)

Comment: `HTTP_PROVIDERS` are the providers for HTTP and `ng.http.Http` the type of the object you want to inject. One of providers knows how to create an instance of this type...