# Angular 2 with javascript Http request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, ecmascript-5

I'm not able to inject http service in angular 2, to my custom service, here is my code:

**Application Service**

```
shell.AppService = shell.Class({
    constructor: [ng.http.Http, function AppService(http){
        var _totalCost = 0;

        var _data = [
            {selected: false, name:"abc", cost: 30},
            {selected: true, name:"lmn", cost: 15},
            {selected: false, name:"opq", cost: 18},
            {selected: false, name:"rst", cost: 42},
            {selected: false, name:"uvw", cost: 12}
        ];

        this.getData = function(){return _data;}

        this.resetSelection = function(){
            for(let i=0;i<_data.length;i++)
                _data[i].selected = false;
        }

        this.calculateCost = function(){
            _totalCost = 0;
            for(let i=0;i<_data.length;i++){
                if(_data[i].selected) _totalCost += _data[i].cost;
            }
            return _totalCost;
        }
    }]
});
```

And here the **main component**:

```
//Main Component.
shell.AppComponent = shell.Component({
    selector: "main-app",
    directives: [shell.ListComponent],
    providers : [shell.AppService, ng.http.HTTP_PROVIDERS],
    template: "<h1>Angular 2 application Example</h1>"+
                   "<list-data></list-data>"
}).Class({
    constructor: function AppComponent(){}
});
```

Here im using **ng.http.Http** and in main component im injecting **ng.http.HTTP_PROVIDERS** still its not working. I took reference from this link: [Angular 2: How to use Http in ES5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33458481/angular-2-how-to-use-http-in-es5)

Can anybody suggest me, where im doing wrong..!

Comment: Here I got **very very** good example for http request in Angular 2 with js: 

http://www.waynehong.com/javascript/angular-2-service-example-javascript/

Comment: But he using different files:

 <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.0/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.0/Rx.umd.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.0/angular2-all.umd.js"></script>

Comment: Same problem here, those files are no longer used by angular 2....